# Windows authentication MVC web api custom authorize attribute dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have custom authorization attribute for ApiController. I am using windows authentication so I get dialog box to enter my credentials.

```
public class APIAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute

public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if ( /* my authorization method which returns true/false */ )
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
}

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("AuthenticationStatus", "NotAuthorized");
    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    return;
}
```

I get 401 response with unauthorized (it is really good for my case), but I don't want to show that credentials box, because I want to replace that with my own dialog box, which will say i.e "You don't have permission for this action!". Any ideas what I have to change in my code ?
I also have read, that it might be IIS settings, but I could not find them.

Comment: You can usually specify this in the web.config BUT it will have no effect if you are making the call using AJAX (using jquery or angularjs or pure javascript) instead of a form post. You will have to include your client code or describe how the calls are being made.

Comment: Now I am calling my web api from angular, but in result I get Authentication required prompt box, and when I press cancel, only then I get 401.

Comment: If you are calling from javascript you want an error and http status code. Client side you can then redirect the user to the correct screen. Without further code and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will not be possible to help you further.

Comment: I feel so failed, actually this code was really good, and everything worked fine,except the fact, that I was using base method for handling unauthorized, not the one I have overriden... that was why I got credentials box and unauthorized response.. Now I don't get that box and status ir 403 Forbidden, which is really great for my use-case. Thanks for trying to help me, Igor :)